# Group actions and cardinality of double cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I was recently asked this in my abstract algebra class on group actions which seems difficult for me and so need the help on:

> Let $ G $ be a group and $ H,K \leq G $ be two subgroups with the groups not necessarily finite. We are to prove for each $ g \in G $ we have the following cardinality of the double coset: $ |HgK| = | K \times (H/H_g) | = | H \times (K/K_g) | $ where we denote: $ H_g = H \cap gKg^{-1} $

Now for the case of finite groups all is OK and basic index arithmetic works but for infinite groups or indices how would I prove equal cardinalities? I should mention I proved $ H \times K $ acts on G via $ (h,k) \cdot g = hgk^{-1} $ and the double coset in question is indeed an orbit so the double cosets form a partition of G but cannot prove the formula. I certainly appreciate the help on proving the formula Thanks

Comment: Consider the left action of $H$ on the left cosets of $K$. The stabilizer is $H_g$ and the size of the orbit is the index $|H:H_g|$ So $|HgK| = |K| \times |H:H_g|$. None of this depends on finiteness.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think I understand but where did the equality $ |HgK| = |K| \times |H:H_g| $ come from?

Comment: $HgK$ is the union of $|H:H_g|$ left cosets of $K$.